# Protobuf how to change inheritance hierarchy without losing backward compatibility

Tags: c#, serialization, hierarchy, protobuf-net

I have a specific use-case for inheritance using protobuf-net which I don't know (if possible) how to handle.

Let's say we have these sample classes (label this as Version 1):

```
public class FooA
{
    public double A { get; set; }
    public double B { get; set; }
}

public class FooB : FooA
{
    public double C { get; set; }
}

public class FooC : FooB
{        
}

public class FooD : FooC
{
    public double D { get; set; }
}

public class FooA1 : FooA
{        
}
```

With the below protobuf's model definition:

```
        Model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();

        Model.Add(typeof(FooA), false)
            .AddSubType(201, typeof(FooB))
            .AddSubType(202, typeof(FooA1))
            .Add(1, "A")
            .Add(2, "B");

        Model[typeof(FooB)]
            .AddSubType(201, typeof(FooC))
            .Add(1, "C");

        Model[typeof(FooC)]
            .AddSubType(201, typeof(FooD));                

        Model[typeof(FooD)]
            .Add(1, "D");
```

I serialize them as following

```
        FooA a = new FooA() {A = 10, B = 20};
        FooB b = new FooB() {A = 10, B = 20, C = 30};
        FooA1 b1 = new FooA1() {A = 100, B = 200};
        FooC c = new FooC() {A = 10, B = 20, C = 30};
        FooD d = new FooD() {A = 10, B = 20, C = 30, D = 40};

        using (var stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, a);
            SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, b);
            SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, b1);
            SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, c);
            SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, d);
        }
```

Helper Methods

```
    public void SerializeWithLengthPrefix<T>(Stream stream, T obj)
    {
        var serializationContext = new ProtoBuf.SerializationContext() { Context = this };
        Model.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, obj, typeof(T), PrefixStyle.Base128, 1, serializationContext);
    }

    public T DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<T>(Stream stream, out long bytesRead, out bool haveObject)
    {
        var serializationContext = new ProtoBuf.SerializationContext() { Context = this };

        return (T)Model.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, null, typeof(T), PrefixStyle.Base128, 1, null, out bytesRead, out haveObject, serializationContext);
    }
```

Now I need to change the inheritance hierarchy in this way (label this as Version 2):

```
public class FooA
{
    public double A { get; set; }
    public double B { get; set; }
}

public class FooB : FooA
{
    public double C { get; set; }
}

public class FooC : FooA1/*FooB*/
{
    public double C { get; set; }
}

public class FooD : FooC
{
    public double D { get; set; }
}

public class FooA1 /*: FooA*/
{
    public double A { get; set; }
    public double B { get; set; }
}
```

And also Model definition according to it, trying to preserve the same id for each class defined previously.

```
       Model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();

        Model.Add(typeof(FooA), false)
            .AddSubType(201, typeof(FooB))
            //.AddSubType(202, typeof(FooA1))
            .Add(1, "A")
            .Add(2, "B");

        Model.Add(typeof(FooA1), false)
            .Add(1, "A")
            .Add(2, "B");

        Model[typeof(FooB)]
            //.AddSubType(201, typeof(FooC))
            .Add(1, "C");

        Model[typeof(FooA1)]
            .AddSubType(201, typeof(FooC));

        Model[typeof(FooC)]
            .Add(1, "C")
            .AddSubType(201, typeof(FooD));                

        Model[typeof(FooD)]
            .Add(1, "D");
```

Now I deserialize the file stored with Version 1 and I check for types defined in the model: they're the same than the one during serialization with Version 1.

[image: Model types definition]

But when I check for objects values I see that FooC has been deserialized as FooD and D value is always equal to 0.

[image: Deserialized values]

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to handle this?

**UPDATE**

Trying to debug the protobuf-net source code when *FooC* is deserialized with Version 2, the method *[RuntimeTypeModel](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/d12763cd24820c4861bf723efd3d2d26aa7fcb13/src/protobuf-net/Meta/RuntimeTypeModel.cs).GetKey()* starts from the base class (getBaseKey=true), correctly gets *FooA1* (key=2) but finally it gets *FooD* object instead of *FooC*. Maybe is there a way to handle this method in a different way to allow a scenario like this?

[image: protobuf debug]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Marc explanation, I found a way to handle this specific use-case by using some helper classes.

I post my solution here wether can be helpful to someone else.

Version 2 can be defined as follows:

```
public class FooA
{
    public double A { get; set; }
    public double B { get; set; }
}

public class FooAFake
{
    public double A { get; set; }
    public double B { get; set; }
}

public class FooB : FooA
{
    public double C { get; set; }
}

public class FooBFake : FooAFake
{
    public double C { get; set; }
}

public class FooC : FooBFake
{        
}

public class FooD : FooC
{
    public double D { get; set; }
}

public class FooA1 : FooAFake
{        
}
```

And Model in this way:

```
        Model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();

        Model.Add(typeof(FooA), false)
            .AddSubType(201, typeof(FooB))
            //.AddSubType(202, typeof(FooA1))
            .Add(1, "A")
            .Add(2, "B");

        Model[typeof(FooB)]
            //.AddSubType(201, typeof(FooC))
            .Add(1, "C");

        Model[typeof(FooC)]
            .AddSubType(201, typeof(FooD));                

        Model[typeof(FooD)]
            .Add(1, "D");

        Model.Add(typeof(FooAFake), false)
            .AddSubType(201, typeof(FooBFake))
            .AddSubType(202, typeof(FooA1))
            .Add(1, "A")
            .Add(2, "B");

        Model[typeof(FooBFake)]
            .AddSubType(201, typeof(FooC))
            .Add(1, "C");
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way of making that change without breaking compatibility. My advice when we anyone gets tied into a knot: split the "real" types and the serialization types apart into separate type models that don't need to be a 1:1 map to each-other. Then you can do whatever you want to the "real" types (the domain model), and you just *project* those values into the serialization model, which might have different rules and be more convenient for the serializer. In this case, the serialization types might not be a 1:1 map in terms of the inheritance tree.

The other option is to forcibly migrate the old data, so: deserialize it with the old layout, and re-serialize it with the new layout. This is embracing the inheritance change, rather than trying to pretend it didn't happen.

---

The following is to show the resultant .proto layout to explain why `FooC` ends up as `FooD` in v2:

v1 starting from `FooA` - `FooC` is 201, 201 (`FooD` is 201, 201, 201)

```proto
syntax = "proto2";

message FooA {
   optional double A = 1;
   optional double B = 2;
   oneof subtype {
      FooB FooB = 201;
      FooA1 FooA1 = 202;
   }
}
message FooA1 {
}
message FooB {
   optional double C = 1;
   oneof subtype {
      FooC FooC = 201;
   }
}
message FooC {
   oneof subtype {
      FooD FooD = 201;
   }
}
message FooD {
   optional double D = 1;
}
```

v2 starting from `FooA1` - `FooD` is 201, 201:

```proto
syntax = "proto2";

message FooA1 {
   optional double A = 1;
   optional double B = 2;
   oneof subtype {
      FooC FooC = 201;
   }
}
message FooC {
   optional double C = 1;
   oneof subtype {
      FooD FooD = 201;
   }
}
message FooD {
   optional double D = 1;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Marc, I cannot understand why object FooC is deserialized as FooD with Version 2. I tried to debug it (see the update in the post) but I cannot understand why this happens. Can you explain better why this scenario cannot be handled? Thanks.

Comment: @ilCosmico schema added (see `Model.GetSchema(Type)`) to explain the `FooC`/`FooD` thing

Comment: Hi @Marc, thanks for the explanation, now it's more clear and I'd like to try a solution that came in my mind. Is important the order of types defined in the model? I mean, is important to preserve 0=FooA, 1=FooB, 2=FooC...etc, or just fields id and subType id must be the same in Version1 and Version2?

Comment: @ilCosmico the numbers are what matters; that's *why* you need to provide explicit numbers

Comment: Ok, but I don't set a number when adding a new type. Does this mean that I need to be careful how type's array is filled or is there a way to define a particular number (id) for a new type when I add it with Model.Add(typeof(myNewType))?

Comment: I made some tests trying to change the order in which types are added to the Model and I always can read back the serialized file. Maybe there is some hidden trick that handles this, but it works :) Moreover, looking at .proto layout you posted, I can see numbers only for fields and subtype, but not for the object its self. e.g. for object FooA1 v2 I see A=1, B=2, FooC=201, but FooA1 has not a number.

Comment: @ilCosmico oh, it doesn't matter in what order you add *root* types - I mean when adding sub-types (and fields)